# Fifty-Four is what you get

Tags: riddle, word

*Add*, a **fruit** is what you get

*Remove*, **fifty-four** is what you get

What word am I looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could be the word:

> **LIVE**

If you *add a letter*, you can make:

> **OLIVE** - a fruit.

If you *remove a letter*, you can make:

> **LIV** - i.e. 54 in Roman numerals.

Comment: Yes, this is correct!

Comment: Quick there :) I was planning to make it  'five and four is what you get'. Would've probably been slightly harder

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ha, yeah that was the line that I hit on first and it was a quick step to find the other, so disguising that line more would definitely make it a bit more difficult...